# flutter retrieves data from JSON using REST API in the search box

Tags: flutter, dart

flutter retrieves data from JSON using REST API in the search box
I've also coded the search box, but I can only see the JSON for the REST API and no search box, and I don't know how to do it. Please help me
There is no error, but the search box does not appear.

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u9EdBHnp_EsO4bT6kEtjleRAowqyg4_f)

```
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar:  AppBar(
        title: Text('widgettitle'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (getJSONData)  {

                },
                controller: editingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Search",
                    hintText: "Search",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      data[index]['publisher'].toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black, ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. To make your question successful, please expand it explaining what you have tried and providing the code necessary to understand and replicate your problem.

Comment: Add some code which you think has the error to help understand people to help you.

Comment: I think it's wrong here.